# Generic tables Backend editor in TYPO3?

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typoscript

I'm looking for some generic tables Backend editor in TYPO3. I have plenty of DB tables and I need to make them editable by Backend User. I have tried to find some extension but without luck:( Do I have to create custom Backend module for each of tables?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With native "List" module You could edit almostly all in the table.

Sometimes, You need to adjust the TCA configuration for that.